# where do I find detailed info on the user entity and how do I get an instance of it?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Hello.

We have a custom solution here where the vendor uses Microsoft Dynamics  as base. They have created a custom entity (contactrelationships) and one of the fields/attributes of the entity is something called "ownerid". I looked at the GUI/website
 and it seems this attribute is just a user from the user entity.

I've searched the net  for info on the user entity (I've downloaded the ERD too Microsoft provides) and I cannot find info on it. There are various stuff that talks about user and teams but nothing like this MSDN
[page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328530(v=crm.5).aspx) on the contacts entity.

Basically I have a custom entity here where one of the attributes/fields (name is ownerid) uses the user entity. I verified this when I viewed the entity on the website and clicking on the ownerid lead me to the user management webpage.

I want to create a new instance of this custom entity via c# and properly assign the ownerid attribute. I've use EntityReference before but I'm not sure this is the right way to go.

Can you please help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ownerid` is a special attribute inside Dynamics CRM. If an entity is created with Ownwership set to `User or Team`, the attribute `ownerid` is created automatically inside the entity (along with other attributes like `createdby` and `modifiedby`).

`ownerid` can handle `SystemUser` records or `Team` records, the metadata for `SystemUser` is here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328525(v=crm.5).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328525%28v=crm.5%29.aspx)

and the metadata for `Team is here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328312(v=crm.5).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328312%28v=crm.5%29.aspx)

The field is an `EntityReference` so you need to use the syntax (if you want to specify a different user from the one that is actually creating the record)

```
entity["ownerid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", userId);
```

But because this attribute is special, the above syntax is valid only when you create a new record, if you want to modify an existing record, you need to use an `AssignRequest`

```
Guid accountId = new Guid("90F8889F-EB95-E781-8417-000C44420CBC");
Guid newOwnerId = new Guid("A8AA28B4-9015-DF11-8062-000E0CA08051");

AssignRequest assignRequest = new AssignRequest
        {
            Assignee = new EntityReference("systemuser", newOwnerId),
            Target = new EntityReference("account", accountId)
        };
service.Execute(assignRequest);
```